# is n-1 th derivative continuous in closed interval if n th derivative exists in open interval

Tags: real-analysis

Assume the $n$th derivative of a function $f(x)$ exists in an open interval $(a,b)$.

It is obvious that the $n-1$th derivative of $f(x)$ is continuous in $(a,b)$ but is it always true that $n-1$ th derivative of $f(x)$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 1):

A simple counterexample would be $n=1$ with $(a,b)=(0,1)$ and $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{when }0<x<1 \\ 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

---

For $n>1$ we'll need to be slightly more careful to ensure that the $(n-1)$th derivative at least exists everywhere, but we could take $n=2$, $(a,b)=(0,1)$ and
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2\sin(1/x) & \text{when }x>0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean that my assertion is correct or my assertion is wrong and that you had given a counterexample

Comment: @felicsmoses: What do you think? Is your assertion true about my examples?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly not. Let's take the example $n=1$, the $0$th derivative being $f(x)$ itself. $f(x)$ could perhaps be discontinuous at $[a,b]$. An example could be the floor function over $[0,1]$.

Comment: But in the statement of Taylor's Theorem it states 'first n-1 th derivatives are continuous in [a,b] and n th derivative is differentiable in (a,b). What does it mean?

Comment: read my question clearly and try to explain clearly

Comment: You'll have to give me the form of the theorem you are using. Taylor's theorem is often stated in many different ways.